# windows 7. older dell desktop using Chrome. Can a virus cause unwanted google searches to appear

Tags: hard-drive, memory

I am pretty sure this can not happen, but I wanted to ask.  If you have a virus on your computer, can it cause a google image search to show up that you did not do yourself?

Comment: Yes; Of course it can

Answer (score 1):

Like in many other cases: Yes, it actually can.

There are **alot** of viruses that alter search results, trying to "force" a user to visit malicious websites or something similar. Some of these might hook into the browser (Chrome in this case) or even function as a proxy, possibly reading encrypted data by installing a certificate into the "trust space" of your PC. Be aware.

Comment: ok.  I found pron stuff on my husbands computer today.  He is saying he has a virus that caused the search engine to bring these pictures up.  I just wanted to make sure I'm not being stupid here,  I do not want to accuse at all.  So I will go with this answer.  One thing that is bothering me is its been three different searches to three different groups of images.  I hope this is just a bug like he says.  Thanks for the answer